# Is there a way for keeping the title aligned, when adding a subtitle, in React Native Elements?

Tags: react-native, listitem, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native Elements (1.0) to display my `<ListItem />`s. I was wondering if there is a way for keeping the title on the same line it was when adding a subtitle?

Here is what I currently have, which is wrong:

[image]

What I would like to have is the "1x" to be aligned with "Filterkaffee" and "Klein" and have the subtitle below.

### Edit

Also here is the ListItem's code:

```
<ListItem
  title={item.name}
  leftElement=<Text style={styles.amount}>{item.amount}x</Text>
  rightTitle={`${item.price.label}`}
  subtitle={`${
    item.items.length > 0
      ? item.customChoiceItems.reduce((acc, customChoiceItem, index, arr) => {
          acc += customChoiceItem.name;
          acc += index < arr.length - 1 ? "\n" : "";
          return acc;
        }, "")
      : null
  }`}
  onPress={() => {}}
/>
```

Comment: you can use flex-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `leftElement` prop on the ListItem component; I'm assuming you're using version `1.0.0-beta5` of react-native-elements.

The ListItem component has a [`containerStyle`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#containerstyle) prop that you can use to control the styling of the container. By default, it has an `alignItems: 'center'` rule that allows the contents of the ListItem to be centred vertically. Since you want to align them to the top, you can use `alignItems: 'flex-start'`.

```
<ListItem
  title="Filterkaffee"
  leftElement={<Text style={styles.amount}>1x</Text>}
  subtitle="Medium Roast Schokosojakeks"
  rightTitle="Klein"
  containerStyle={{ alignItems: 'flex-start' }}
/>
```

[image]